# Why composer -vvv install/update always downloads all packages from packagist?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I created an empty composer file.

Then I removed the folder .composer from my home directory.

The composer.JSON looks like this now:

```
{
    "name": "name/test",
    "require": {}
}
```

When I run to install or update it starts to download all assets from packagist.org. Why does it have this dependency on packagist even when I do not have it in cache and in composer file?

It takes a while to download all packages. How do I avoid it?

Comment: Which "all packages" are downloaded? Are you sure that it does not pick up another `composer.json`?

Comment: Yes. I solved by removing composer and installed it again.